# Struggling to bind local images in an MvxImageView with MvvmCross

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I can't seem to get images to bind properly in an MvxListView

Here is the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl IconName, Converter=IconSource" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Description" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the converter:

```
public class IconSourceValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //string retval = string.Format("res:{0}", value.ToLower());
        string retval = string.Format("@drawable/{0}", value.ToLower());
        return retval;
    }
}
```

All the images are present in the Drawable folder.

I tried both drawable and res and neither work.

I replaced the MvxImageView with a plain ImageView containing a hard coded android:src and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I always seem to figure these things out just after I have posted a question! I was missing the File and Download Cache plugins. The converter should use res: not drawable. I'll answer my own question when I'm allowed.

Comment: In addition to the `res:` fix, you can also use the custom binding targets `DrawableId` for an int or `DrawableName` for a string instead of `ImageUrl` - these are registered during setup in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L103 and are implemented using code in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxImageViewDrawableNameTargetBinding.cs#L38

Answer (score 4):

I have used this to make it work for me:

```
public class StringToIntValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, int>
            {
                protected override int Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
                {
                    int image = 0;
                    if(value == "song")
                        image = Resource.Drawable.icon_category_song;

                    return image;
                }
            }
```

To use this in the Android layout:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="DrawableId StringToInt(Type)" />
```

In this example "Type" is a string containing the word "song".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ,it's working.Tried with MVXImageview

```
 public class PercentToImageConverter : MvxValueConverter<int, int>   
  {         
   protected override int Convert(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    {    
            switch (value)
            {
                case 10:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent10;
                case 40:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent40;
                case 60:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent60;
                case 80:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent80;
                case 100:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent100;
                default:
                    return Resource.Drawable.Percent0;    
             }

    }

}
```

**Android Layout**

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
   android:layout_width="25dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_height="25dp"
  local:MvxBind="DrawableId PercentToImage(Percent)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml use: local:MvxBind="ImageUrl IconName"
In ViewModel: IconName="res:image_name"

eg.In drawable resource image name like "image_name.png"