# Local source image bind to MvxImageView

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, mvvmcross

```
 public class DrawerView
{
    public string ListItem{get;set;}
    public string icon{ get; set;}
    public DrawerView (string Litems,string ic)
    {
        this.ListItem = Litems;
        this.icon = ic;
    }
}

 public class MainViewModel:MvxViewModel
{
    public List<DrawerView> drawerlist{ get; set;}
    public MainViewModel ()
    {
        drawerlist = new List<DrawerView> ();
        drawerlist.Add (new DrawerView ("Home","@drawable/Home"));
        drawerlist.Add (new DrawerView ("My Addresses","@drawable/Home"));
        drawerlist.Add (new DrawerView ("My Cart","/@drawable/Home"));
        drawerlist.Add (new DrawerView ("My Orders","@drawable/Home"));
        drawerlist.Add (new DrawerView ("Notification","@drawable/Home"));
    }
}


 <Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl 'res:icon'"
    />
```

I can't get image in View when i bing local @drawable/Home image using image url.
how to bind local source image in MvxImageView ? Here in above code icon is my string property and it takes @drawable/images.

Comment: Why are you using `'` around your binding expression?

Comment: I found Example like that on stackoverflow.so I have used it in my app.if I remove it , still not working.

Comment: And do you have a resource inside your drawables folder that is called icon in that exact case?

Comment: No,actually i have a property called icon and in icon i have bunch of images that i want to bind.And all that images are in drawables.

Comment: I have a ListView and all the row of ListView has image and textview.and i want to bind this ListView's image with the local images which are in drawables.

Comment: I have post my code.I hope you will understand it now better.If I use "src icon" still its not working.@Cheesebaron

Comment: I think you need to use DrawableId or DrawableName for this. See my answer in this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27819663/4222823

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using a converter:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:id="@+id/team_trend"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl RowItem.TeamTrendEnum, Converter=TeamTrendImage" />
```

My converter returns the image:

```
public class TeamTrendImageValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var teamTrend = TeamTrendEnumeration.None;

        if (value != null)
            teamTrend = (TeamTrendEnumeration)value;

        switch (teamTrend)
        {
            case TeamTrendEnumeration.High: 
                return "res:th";

            ...                                           
        }

        return "res:none";                  
    }
}
```

Have you tried removing the quotes?

Comment: for the `th`, do I need the `drawable` folder name and `.png` file extension?